# Shrinking url in PHP

Tags: php, url, simplify, shrink

I'm trying to show this url `http://www.xyz.com/catnew/newcat.php` as `http://www.xyz.com/cat`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: You need to redirect it, either in your .htaccess file or by using the header() function in index.php - or whatever file handles requests

Comment: With the assumption that you use apache, I would recommend you to look at `mod_rewrite`

Comment: @Jan Hančič - I want the first url to be displayed as second. Nothing else.

Comment: @Kishor Kumar do you mean the completely PHP-unrelated way? `<a href='http://www.xyz.com/catnew/newcat.php'>http://www.xyz.com/cat</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/]*)$ /catnew/newcat.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

The original URL:

```
http://www.xyz.com/catnew/newcat.php?cat=3
```

The rewritten URL:

```
http://www.xyz.com/cat/3
```

Answer (score 2):

look up tutorials on mod_rewrite, if your on Apache this may be the answer depending on how you want to do it.